# Can you perform CRUD on CouchDB view?

Tags: php, laravel, couchdb, crud

I was wondering can you preform CRUD functionalities on CouchDB view that will update records in the db also?

I am building an PHP, Laravel application that uses CouchDB and views seem good solution as they load faster than DB tables.

I managed to read from the view but I wonder is it possible to add, delete and edit. 
This is first time that I am using Couch so I am not sure am I approaching this the right way.

Comment: Views are queries, so they're effectively read-only. However, there is the `_bulk_docs` API for doing bulk updates/deletes, which is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Views in CouchDB are read-only versions of the data in the database (the same is true in most or all databases, including MySQL, Postgres, etc).  To perform the C, U and D portions of CRUD, you need to use the rest of the CouchDB API.

To create or update, typically use [`PUT /{db}/{doc}`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/document/common.html#put--db-docid), and for delete, use [`DELETE /{db}/{doc}`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/document/common.html#delete--db-docid).

You can batch updates with the [`_bulk_docs`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-bulk-docs) endpoint, as well.